# Fail to use pip in Python 3.4

Tags: python, windows, pip

I used Anaconda to install Python 3.4 under Windows 8. At first, everything is fine, and later the system told me that I need to use `pip install pip --upgrade` to update pip. After I did this, I got some error information on the screen and then pip can no longer be used.

Now when I try to install some packages using pip, there would be some error information:

```
C:\Users\E440>pip
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Program Files\Annaconda\lib\runpy.py", line 170, in _run_module_as_ma
in
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "E:\Program Files\Annaconda\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "E:\Program Files\Annaconda\Scripts\pip.exe\__main__.py", line 5, in <mod
ule>
ImportError: No module named 'pip'
```

I tried several methods, but still can't fix it. Any suggestions?

Comment: Sounds like you just need to upgrade `pip` itself. I suggest getting the file `get-pip.py` from [here](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing.html), run it with `python get-pip.py`, and proceed from there. It should install the newest version of pip, and fix all the other issues.

Comment: I haven't used the Anaconda distribution, but since it has its own `conda` package manager, shouldn't you first try installing `pip` that way?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to `import pip` from your [python](/questions/tagged/python) program; as `pip` is a [linux](/questions/tagged/linux) command, not a [python](/questions/tagged/python) module, this will fail to import the correct program:

```
import pip
```

Instead, call it from your [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) ([linux](/questions/tagged/linux) interpreter):

```
bash-3.2$ pip install module
```

Comment: OP doesn't try to import pip, the error comes after running pip in command line. Also note that the question is about Windows, not Linux.